# How to get ts frame from DJI phantom camera delegate for RTMP streaming to server

Tags: ios, dji-sdk

I am building an iPad application for DJI Phantom drone. I wanted to stream video from drone camera to RTMP server. I am getting the video stream from camera using DJI SDK from camera delegate method.

```
-(void)camera:(DJICamera *)camera didReceiveVideoData:(uint8_t *)videoBuffer length:(size_t)size {

}
```

I wanted to know the concept to send that video buffer as RTMP packet to server. Is there any way to get TS frame from this. I have reviewed LIveKit sdk for RTMP streaming which streams video and audio from iPhone/iPad camera. I wanted to send custom video buffer packet to RTMP server. I have setup my own server for this. You can review sample app provided by DJI 
https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/ios-tutorials/index.html